# Google Analytics sometimes filters my IP address, and sometimes doesn't

Tags: google-analytics

I know for a fact that it sometimes filters my IP and sometimes doesn't, even though I have stayed in the same place while checking (really don't know if that matters).

When I first added the filter I noticed right away I was being filtered since I disappeared from the counter. But now, a few hours later, when I started modifying my webpage (a tumblr if it's of any relevance), I see my session being counted, switched to another post to make sure it was mine, and it was, since google analytics changed the name of the webpage that was active, and there was only one active user. So I added another filter thinking the old one was wrong, didn't delete the first one so there are two separate filters working now, but that didn't seem to work right away. Probably 10 minutes passed and my session was being filtered without changing any of the two filters.

I now checked the filters and both have different ip addresses, what I did to obtain my IP address was just google "what is my ip address?" and click any link.

The first IP is: 190.21.243.5
The second IP is:  190.21.227.235

Both filters are in the format: "Filter" --> "Predefined" --> "Exclude" --> "IP traffic" --> "Equals to " --> IP number --> "Apply to " --> "Every data from the webpage"

Comment: This is off topic as it's not about coding. Your IP may be dynamic, so in which case you can search on SO for similar questions.

Comment: Where can I take this question if it doesn't belong here? And what is SO?

Comment: Try webmasters forum.

Comment: SO is stackoverflow (this site). If you always use the same computer it might be more reliable to use the official opt-out browser extension: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout, or if you still want to see outgoing data install a tool like Fiddler and have it send requests to google-analytics.com to limbo while still returning  a http 200 page found status.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff. I am fairly new to all this so I dont think I could manage to do the second thing you said. 

Is it enough to just install that extension? or is there any other configuration needed to set it up?

Comment: You just need to install the extension (there are versions for all major browsers). It will block Google Analytics tracking on all pages you visit, not just your own.